# Android url Scheme not working

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I am trying to create an URL scheme for my Android application but when i enter the link in the browser it opens the link not the app. So far my code looks like this. The link is formed like this http://myhost.com .

```
<activity android:name=".activities.OpenSchemeActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_open_scheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myhost.com"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Does anyone have any idea why is not working?

Comment: try opening the link from some other app, e.g send a sms with link and  click the link

Comment: try without exported and launchMode, just to see if it works with less configurations...

Comment: if i launch it like nandeesh said is working. Isn't there a way to launch it if the link is called from browser

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that it will NOT work directly from the browser's address bar. No way. Only further server redirects or link clicks can lead you to an app picker. As far as I know, browser doesn't handle URL schemes being typed into address bar as something that could require an Intent call.